# Edit innerHTML of a table from a script

Tags: javascript, jsp

I have this table:

```
 <% for(int i = 0; i < result.length; i++)  { %>

<tr id='player-listing-<%=i %>'>
    <td style="vertical-align: top;"><button onclick="myFunction2(<%=i%>)"id="add<%= i %>">Add</button><br></td>
    <td style="vertical-align: top;"id="Position<%= i %>"><%= result[i][1] %><br></td>
    <td style="vertical-align: top;"id="Player<%= i %>"><%= result[i][3]+" "+result[i][4] %><br></td>
    <td style="vertical-align: top;"id="Team<%= i %>"><%= result[i][7] %><br></td>
    <td style="vertical-align: top;"id="Opponent<%= i %>"><%= result[i][8] %><br></td>
    <td style="vertical-align: top;"id="Projected<%= i %>"><input id="projPoints<%= i %>" name="numLineups" style="width: 35px" value="<%= result[i][5] %>"><br></td>

    <td style="vertical-align: top;"id="Salary<%= i %>"><%= result[i][2] %><br></td>
<tr>
```

And and the add buttons of that table copy that row to this table:

```
<table id='selected-players' style="text-align: top; " border="0" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="2">

<tr>
    <td style="vertical-align: top;">0/55<br></td>
    <td style="vertical-align: top;">Pos<br></td>
    <td style="vertical-align: top;">Player<br></td>
    <td style="vertical-align: top;">Team<br></td>
    <td style="vertical-align: top;">Opponent<br></td>
    <td style="vertical-align: top;">Projected<br></td>
    <td style="vertical-align: top;">Salary<br></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

using this function:

```
function myFunction2(i){
    var table = document.getElementById('selected-players');
    var copyRow = document.getElementById('player-listing-'+i).cloneNode(true);
    copyRow.setAttribute('id', 'selected-row-'+i);
    copyRow.cells[0].innerHTML = '<button onclick="removeRow(this, ' + i + ')">Remove</button>';
    copyRow.cells[5].innerHTML = document.getElementById("projPoints"+i).value;
    table.appendChild(copyRow);
    document.getElementById("add"+i).disabled = true;
}
```

I would like this function to also update the first cell of the 'selected players' table to the number of added rows. For example if the add button was pressed for three rows the result would be "3/55"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question isn't very well formed, so you're getting a poorly-formed answer.

Set a variable (eg `numPlayersSelected` outside your function that tracks the number of players you've added. Increment it when you add a player, then set the `0/55` cell's innerHTML to `numPlayersSelected + "/" + 55` (or numTotalPlayers).

[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/e9hhou37/)

Comment: Just got a chance to look at this. Thanks it was actually very helpful!